# Failed to install rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gdebi, rstudio

Good folks, please help.
I downloaded rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb from https://download1.rstudio.org
 then checked its MD5, then installed deb using gdebi, and failed:

```
$ sudo gdebi -n rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
(Reading database ... 255728 files and directories currently 
 installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb ...

Unpacking rstudio (1.0.143) ...
dpkg: error processing archive rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.4.0.dpkg-new': 
Operation not permitted

Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-
 0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

I tried earlier versions of RStudio i.e. 0.98.113, 0.99.489, 0.99.896. They all failed on the line:
    Unpacking rstudio (x.xx.xxx)

I also tried after each failure to call: 
    sudo apt-get -f install
No luck...

FWIW, R 3.4 is working fine with Emacs (ESS), but I want to try RStudio.

Thanks a lot